# Notebook crashes and restarts when installing wireless adapter

Tags: drivers, wifi-driver

I am using an Acer Emachines notebook model E730G. 
I have recently upgraded from windows 7 to 8 pro. 
When I try to connect to my School's wifi network it simply does not connect but it can find the wifi network. When I try to upgrade my drivers all the other drivers update and work perfectly but when it comes to the wireless adapter, my notebook crashes (I get a blue screen) during installation and then restarts.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which website are you using to update your drivers? I'm guessing you're using some kind of application since you said you're upgrading all your drivers at once and once it get to installing the wireless adapter it crashes.

Comment: I was using Driver Pack Solution

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend confirming you have all the appropriate drivers. The best way to get almost all the drivers automatically is by running Windows Update.

After you have done that, verify you have the correct chipset drivers. If not, you can visit this [link](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/Chipset/Chipset_Intel_9.1.1.1024_W7x64_A.zip?acerid=634069231151016082&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=E%20SERIES&Step3=E730&OS=711&LC=en&BC=EMACHINES&SC=PA_6E) and directly download the driver for your computer. I have noticed that there are no current Windows 8 drivers for your laptop either. So you might have to download the ones for Windows 7 (x64 or x86 depending on your architecture).

If Windows updates did not find the wireless adapter drivers for you automatically, you can [visit this website](http://www.emachines.com/ec/en/US/content/drivers) and download the appropriate Intel, Broadcom or Atheros driver. To figure out what the model of your adapter is, follow these steps.

1. Open Device Manager
2. Expand the Network adapters
3. Right click on the adapter and click properties.
4. Open the Details tab.
5. Change the Property dropdown to Hardware Ids
6. Note the VEN_XXXX, X is the 4 digit hexadecimal value for the vendor's ID.
7. Match the ID below to find what brand your network adapter is.

[image]

Vendor IDs (Each one has two):

```
Intel    - 8086, 8087
Broadcom - 14E4, 0A5C
Atheros  - 168C, 1969
```

Download the appropriate driver from the website linked above and let me know the results.

EDIT: The drivers listed on the website only include Windows 7 drivers and not Windows 8. You will need to contact the manufacturer of the wireless adapter driver (Broadcom) and provide them the details for the hardware on your computer and they should be able to provide you with a solution. Meanwhile, you can try and run the setup in compatibility mode.

1. Extract the Driver folder onto the desktop.
2. Right click the Setup.exe file and Open its properties.
3. Click the Compatibility tab.
4. Check the "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" and make sure the the "Windows 7" option is selected from the dropdown list.

[image]

Comment: I get this Error when installing the appropriate broadcom driver:
Error: "Setup.rul 343" has occurred and Setup cannot continue.

Comment: Ok, what you might have to do is request Windows 8 drivers from the manufacturer since Win 7 drivers might be incompatible. Before you do that or while you're waiting on the response from them, you can try running the setup in compatibility mode. I edited my answer to show you how that can be done. Also, what architecture (x64 or x86) is your OS?